# Generate fingerprint with PGP Public Key

Tags: gpgpu, fingerprint, pgp, openpgp

I have a PGP public key and I need to get the fingerprint for it.

My Public key is as such:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
mQlDBF4w............................
.
.
.
=uYgH
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

I tried using the command `gpg --with-fingerprint key.txt` but it gives me the following output and there is no fingerprint in it:

```
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
pub   rsa4096 2020-01-28 [SC]
uid           my_key <something@something.com>
sub   rsa4096 2020-01-28 [E]
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
gpg --import --import-options show-only key.txt
```

edit:

looks like same question as in https://serverfault.com/q/1059871/391060 which was linked to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/335669/223965